# Не запускается Steam на GNU/Linux Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia, steam

у меня старый ПК, поставил на него Debian 9 и теперь мне надо поставить Steam. Сделал я это следующим образом:

1. В /etc/apt/sources.list добавил:

   deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

Следующие команды:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install steam
```

Установил 32-библиотеки OpenGL:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386
```

Но при попытке запустить Steam выдает ошибку:

```
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2018-12-07 12:38:56] Startup - updater built Nov 23 2016 01:05:42
*** Error in `/home/selinpc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam': free(): invalid pointer: 0xffdaef30 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6738a)[0xf730b38a]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6dfc7)[0xf7311fc7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6e806)[0xf7312806]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XFree+0x18)[0xf7692058]
/home/selinpc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam(+0x51406)[0x565d5406]
/home/selinpc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam(+0x520ee)[0x565d60ee]
/home/selinpc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam(+0x22420)[0x565a6420]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf6)[0xf72bc286]
/home/selinpc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam(+0x25ae9)[0x565a9ae9]
======= Memory map: ========
56584000-56935000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 10092960                           /home/selinpc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
56935000-56949000 r--p 003b1000 08:06 10092960                           /home/selinpc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
56949000-56956000 rw-p 003c5000 08:06 10092960                           /home/selinpc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
56956000-5697a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
57ec3000-57f99000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
f4a00000-f4a65000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f4a65000-f4b00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f4b8e000-f4ba1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1314996                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
f4ba1000-f4ba2000 r--p 00012000 08:01 1314996                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
f4ba2000-f4ba3000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 1314996                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
f4ba3000-f6457000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1315063                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.384.130
f6457000-f6477000 rwxp 018b4000 08:01 1315063                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.384.130
f6477000-f6add000 r-xp 018d4000 08:01 1315063                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.384.130
f6add000-f6b91000 rw-p 01f39000 08:01 1315063                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.384.130
f6b91000-f6ba5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6ba5000-f6ba9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1315064                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnvidia-tls.so.384.130
f6ba9000-f6baa000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1315064                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnvidia-tls.so.384.130
f6baa000-f6c6e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1721613                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGL.so.384.130
f6c6e000-f6c8e000 rwxp 000c4000 08:01 1721613                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGL.so.384.130
f6c8e000-f6cba000 r-xp 000e4000 08:01 1721613                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGL.so.384.130
f6cba000-f6cbf000 rw-p 00110000 08:01 1721613                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia/current/libGL.so.384.130
f6cbf000-f6cc3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6cc3000-f7094000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7094000-f722f000 r--p 00000000 08:01 1048870                            /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
f722f000-f7231000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7231000-f724a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1187287                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0.8.3
f724a000-f724b000 ---p 00019000 08:01 1187287                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0.8.3
f724b000-f724c000 r--p 00019000 08:01 1187287                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0.8.3
f724c000-f724d000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 1187287                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0.8.3
f724d000-f7252000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1314990                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f7252000-f7253000 r--p 00004000 08:01 1314990                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f7253000-f7254000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 1314990                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f7254000-f7256000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1314988                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
f7256000-f7257000 r--p 00001000 08:01 1314988                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
f7257000-f7258000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 1314988                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
f7258000-f7274000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1187242                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
f7274000-f7275000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 1187242                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
f7275000-f7276000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 1187242                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
f7276000-f7278000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7278000-f72a2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1314992                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f72a2000-f72a3000 r--p 00029000 08:01 1314992                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f72a3000-f72a4000 rw-p 0002a000 08:01 1314992                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f72a4000-f7455000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1187247                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
f7455000-f7457000 r--p 001b0000 08:01 1187247                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
f7457000-f7458000 rw-p 001b2000 08:01 1187247                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so
f7458000-f745b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f745b000-f7474000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1187261                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
f7474000-f7475000 r--p 00018000 08:01 1187261                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
f7475000-f7476000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 1187261                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.24.so
f7476000-f7478000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7478000-f75e8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1315000                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
f75e8000-f75ee000 r--p 0016f000 08:01 1315000                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
f75ee000-f75ef000 rw-p 00175000 08:01 1315000                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
f75ef000-f75f2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f75f2000-f75f5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1187250                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
f75f5000-f75f6000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1187250                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
f75f6000-f75f7000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1187250                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.24.so
f75f7000-f764a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1187251                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.24.so
f764a000-f764b000 r--p 00052000 08:01 1187251                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.24.so
f764b000-f764c000 rw-p 00053000 08:01 1187251                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.24.so
f764c000-f7653000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1187263                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.24.so
f7653000-f7654000 r--p 00006000 08:01 1187263                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.24.so
f7654000-f7655000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 1187263                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.24.so
f7655000-f779e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1314994                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
f779e000-f779f000 ---p 00149000 08:01 1314994                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
f779f000-f77a0000 r--p 00149000 08:01 1314994                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
f77a0000-f77a3000 rw-p 0014a000 08:01 1314994                            /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
f77ac000-f77b5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f77b5000-f77b6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f77b6000-f77b7000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
f77b7000-f77b8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f77b8000-f77b9000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
f77b9000-f77bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f77bc000-f77be000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vvar]
f77be000-f77c0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vdso]
f77c0000-f77d0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1187243                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
f77d0000-f77d1000 r-xp 00010000 08:01 1187243                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
f77d1000-f77e3000 r-xp 00011000 08:01 1187243                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
f77e3000-f77e4000 r--p 00022000 08:01 1187243                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
f77e4000-f77e5000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 1187243                            /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.24.so
ffd92000-ffdb3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack]
Aborted
tar: Это не похоже на tar-архив
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/selinpc/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Система:

```
Linux debian-pc 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)
```

Может кто с таким уже сталкивался, или знает как решить, буду благодарен. Спасибо.